# How to select sequential elements from a list?

Tags: list, python

Roughly speaking I am looking for a more elegant alternative for this snippet:

```
# my_list = range(6) # example list
my_list = ["this", "is", "an", "example", "list"]
max = len(my_list)
for i, elem in enumerate(my_list, start=1):
     if i < max:
         print elem, my_list[i]
```

which produces:

```
this is
is an
an example
example list
```

Is there some builtin for that?

**Edit:** I should have said, that I took `range(6)` as a representant for any iterable to avoid confusion. The goal was to iterate over an iterable pairwise pictured by the result above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually do this:

```
# x = range(6)
x = ["this", "is", "an", "example", "list"]

for prv, nxt in zip(x, x[1:]):
    print prv, nxt
```

Comment: However, this won't work in `python3` since `range` is a generator.

Comment: I just wrote `range(6)` as an example of an iterable. I should have chosen something more general.

Comment: @strcat: As far as I understand, `range` is just a placeholder for an example list. I won't really do this for `range` :). Let me edit to be more clear.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought you might want something that worked for generators too.

Comment: @Avaris: That is exactly how I understood and adapted your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @strcat, yeah, my fault. Should have stated more precicely what I needed. :-)

Comment: @strcat: Actually, range *does* work like this in Python 3.2 (though not 3.1) -- range(6)[1:] == range(1,6) -- but I agree this is a special case.

Answer (score 1):

There is no builtin, but the docs for the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.2/library/itertools.html) module contains definition of the `pairwise`  function that does the same.